# .txt file into 2D Char* Array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I'm fairly new to C++ and I'm working on point of sale program from a class in which I will need to read in the menu option along with the price. I'm attempting to read in a .txt file into a 2D Char* but I keep on getting the error message

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)
```

from line containing

```
inFile >> array[i][j];
```

I'm assuming this error is arising due to the way that I'm trying to assign values to each element in the array. I'm sure how to accomplish it.

```
// Main function
int main (){

    char *array[4][3];
    string fileName;
    vector<string>order;

    fileName = fileLoc();
    getMenu(fileName, array);

    return 0;
}

string fileLoc(){
    string file;
    cout << "Enter file name or location: ";
    cin >> file;
    return file;
}

void getMenu(string fileName, char *array[][3]){
    ifstream inFile(fileName.c_str());
    if (!inFile){
        cout << "File failed to open\n";
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i){
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j){
            inFile >> array[i][j];
            cout << array[i][j] << endl;
        }
    }
    inFile.close();
}
```

The .txt file I am reading from looks like such

```
B Burger 3
S Soda 1
F Fries 2
C Chips 1.5
```

Comment: Since this is C++, use `std::string` and `std::vector` whenever possible. This avoids a *lot* of problems. Strangely you have a `vector` here you never use.

Comment: The shown code declares an array of pointers. These pointers are not initialized, so they contain random garbage. The shown code then attempts to write characters to those uninitialized pointers, which are random garbage. This obviously results in a crash. That's the explanation you're looking for.

Comment: This `char *array[4][3]` declaration makes no sense. You can't read from `inFile` directly into an uninitialized `char*`, that's not going to do anything. Make it `std::vector<std::tuple<char, std::string, int>>` for that kind of data, or even better, make a proper `struct`.

Comment: @tadman the 'vector' i had initialized was going to be used to hold all the items ordered, but I had a feeling that using a 'vector' was going to be a better option. I was staying away from 'struct' as it was not a topic that we had covered yet. Appreciate your help.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik that makes complete sense, the answer was too obvious. Thanks

Comment: You'll have to use `struct`, and a very simple one with a `char`, `std::string` and `int` property, or you'll need to use `std::tuple` unless you're happy with all three of these being just strings. In C++ you can't have an array of different things, everything in that array must be of the same type.